why cant i access the location in char pointer array with dereference to int pointer as index
im making a project and i was getting an error out of nowhere supposedly so i went into debug mode and couldn't find the error but the error only occurred in a specific place so i copied the code and ran it and the error repeated. i couldn't search as to why it was giving an error as far as i know this should work.
in the code below i  tried with direct assigning and it worked but i want to know why the pointer dereference one didn't work.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int assign(char**,char*);

int main(){
    char **arr = calloc(9,sizeof(char*));
    char *ele1 = "hello1";

    assign(arr,ele1);
    
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    }
}

int assign(char **arr,char *ele1){
    for(int *i=0;*i<2;(*i)++){
        arr[*i]=ele1;       
     }
    // for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    //  arr[i]=ele1;        
    // }
}

i commented the first 3 lines in assign function and uncommented the remaining and tried and it worked. here im only assigning 2 values but that shouldnt give any unknown behaviour

for(int *i=0;*i<2;(*i)++): i is a pointer initiazlied to 0 i.e. NULL. then *i and (*i)++ attempts to dereference a NULL pointer which is UB (Undefined Behavior).

I would suggest looking for some more resources on learning the C language, specifically on how pointers are used. int *i=0 creates a "pointer to int" variable i, and assigns the value 0 (NULL) to it (0 is assigned to the pointer not to an int object). Accesses to *i illegally dereferences a NULL pointer.

Let's analyze this loop:
for(int *i=0;*i<2;(*i)++){
    arr[*i]=ele1;       
}

int *i=0 - i is defined as a pointer to int and initialized to 0 (i.e.  it is initialized to a NULL pointer).
Then you have 3 places where you dereference it (using *i):
(1) *i<2
(2) (*i)++
(3) arr[*i]=ele1;
But dereferencing a NULL pointer invokes UB (Undefined Behavior).
But in any case an index into an array should not be a pointer, but rather an integral value like int.
In the commented out version i in an int (which is perfectly valid as an index into an array), not a pointer to int and initializing it to 0 is exactly what you need.
A side note:
assign is declared to return an int, so either return some relevant value, or change it to be a void function.

i dont get it how does initialising *i to 0 makes it null (does initialising a pointer to 0 make it null?, and increasing null value is giving me error?), then why doesn't the commented out code give error?
and do i have to use int instead of int pointer

@neo yes, int *i=0 is defining i to be a pointer and initialize it to null. i is a pointer i.e. it contains an address (of an int). Address 0 is not a valid one, and the language specifies it to be considered a null pointer.

@neo, I think you are not understanding the difference between a pointer (e.g. i) and the thing to which it points (e.g. *i), and / or not understanding the syntax of initializers.  int *i = 0; declares i as a pointer to int, and initializes the pointer with value 0, which for historical reasons is a null pointer constant, equivalent in this contexty to NULL.  Afterward, you have a pointer variable whose value does not (at that time) point to anything.  No int is created. While i it does not point to anything, any use of *i is nonsensical.
